# How to Sniff packet on OS X from all my wireless network

Tags: macos, packet-sniffers

I want to sniff packets from all my devices in my network.
I try using `Wireshark` but in this case i can only see my packets and not from other devices.
So i found [this](http://www.iwaxx.com/debookee/) great tool, this tool can scan my network and activate target on specific devices in my network and start sniffing but after that i want to save this packets in to `PCAP file` but this tool only can save it into `txt file`.
Someone may know this kind of tool ?

Answer (score 0):

> I try using Wireshark but in this case i can only see my packets and not from other devices.

Have you tried turning monitor mode on in Wireshark?

That'll return encrypted packets on a "protected" network, so you'll need to provide the password for the network and, for networks using WPA/WPA2 (which most probably are, these days, as WEP is too easy to crack), you'll have to capture the initial "EAPOL handshake" for each device, so you'd probably have to start capturing and then put each device on the network to sleep and wake it up.  See the ["how to decrypt 802.11"](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) page on the Wireshark Wiki for more details.